# Send Json response using Jersey from MongoDb

Tags: java, json, mongodb, rest, jersey

I have the following code. I want to return all documents present in `catalog` as a json response. I am able to print all documents using `DBCursor`.

```
@Path("/allmusic")
public class GetAllMusic {

    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @GET
    public void getAllSongs(@Context HttpHeaders httpHeaders) throws UnknownHostException {

        DB db = (new MongoClient("localhost",27017)).getDB("sampledb");
        DBCollection dbCollection = db.getCollection("catalog");

        DBCursor cursor = dbCollection.find();

        while(cursor.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.println(cursor.next());
        }
    }


}
```

How can I return all the documents as a json response? Pardon if my question is silly, I am still a beginner.

**EDIT**
I have made following additions to the code:

GetAllMusic.java

```
 @Path("/allmusic")
    public class GetAllMusic {
        @GET
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        @Path("/playlist")
        public Response getAllSongs(@Context HttpHeaders httpHeaders)
         throws UnknownHostException, JsonProcessingException {

                DB db = (new MongoClient("localhost",27017)).getDB("xmusicdb");
                DBCollection dbCollection = db.getCollection("catalog");

                DBCursor cursor = dbCollection.find();

                List<CatalogPojo> result = new ArrayList<>();
                while(cursor.hasNext()) {
                    result.add(new CatalogPojo(cursor.next()));
                }
                String json = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(result);
                return Response.ok(json, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
            }

        }
```

CatalogPojo.java

```
public class CatalogPojo {

    private String title, artist, album, year;


    /*CatalogPojo(String title, String artist, String album, String year){

    }*/

    public CatalogPojo(DBObject next) {

    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getArtist() {
        return artist;
    }

    public void setArtist(String artist) {
        this.artist = artist;
    }

    public String getAlbum() {
        return album;
    }

    public void setAlbum(String album) {
        this.album = album;
    }

    public String getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(String year) {
        this.year = year;
    }
}
```

http://localhost:xxxx/xmusic/allmusic/playlist On accessing this url I am getting a 404. I think there is something wrong with my pojo file or `List<CatalogPojo>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@SOlsson solution is excellent but following code solves the problem in less number of lines. It responds with a valid json string.

```
@Path("/allmusic")
public class GetAllMusic {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/playlist")
    public Response getAllSongs(@Context HttpHeaders httpHeaders) throws UnknownHostException {


        DB db = (new MongoClient("localhost",27017)).getDB("musicdb");
        DBCollection dbCollection = db.getCollection("catalog");
        DBCursor cursor = dbCollection.find();

        JSON json =new JSON();
        @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
        String serialize = json.serialize(cursor);
        System.out.println(serialize);

        return Response.ok(serialize, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there. Try this:

```
@Path("v1")
public class GetAllMusic {
    @GET
    @Path("/allmusic")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getAllSongs {
        ...
        List<AppropriatePojo> result = new ArrayList<>();
        while(cursor.hasNext()) {
            result.add(new AppropriatePojo(cursor.next()));
        }
        String json = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(result);
        return Response.ok(json, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
    }
```

Then access localhost:xxxx/v1/allmusic either with your browser or with thje Chorme plugin PostMan.

Comment: Thanks. What is <AppropriatePojo>?

Comment: Pojo=Plain Old java Object. Just a Java class with the properties you want to return. I don't know what's in your cursor but let say it returns a list of people's names and age. Then create a Pojo (ie a simple Java class) that has the (private) int variable age and the (private) String variable name. Add a setter and a getter (Eclipse can do it for you) for each (a total of 4 methods), and you have a Pojo. Then you can add a constructor that takes a name and an age parameter so it gets easier to initialize objects.

Comment: I am getting a 404 error. I am sure there is something wrong with my pojo file. Thanks.

Comment: I have added my updated code in the question description.

Comment: Can you please elaborate why exactly are we using pojo class here?

Comment: I figured it would be easier to see what's going on if a separate Pojo was used. And it contributes to the separation of internal and "public" classes. 
One error in the code above is that the constructor 'CatalogPojo(DBObject next)' is empty. All the parameters have to be set. Eg this.title = next.extractTheTitleSomehow();

Comment: I was able to solve the problem in less lines of code. Thanks.